# How to binding Image from view-model in another dll?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding

I have a WPF Window project and a image control with it.
I write another dll project and this will be the window's View-Model.
this dll project include a png file called "h.png", i'm going to binding it as a source to then WPF Window project.
I set image binding but it does not work,
could anyone tell me that how to binding a image source from another dll project?

my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace vm
{
    public class VMClass
    {
        BitmapImage img;

        public BitmapImage Img
        {
            get { return img; }
            set { img = value; }
        }
        public VMClass()
        {
            img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("h.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


        }
    }
}
```

my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ImageBindingApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:vm;assembly=vm"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:VMClass/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
            <Image Source="{Binding Img}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure that h image was added as resource (you can check this in picture properties):

[image]

2) Change your uri string ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)) to this:

```
 new BitmapImage(new Uri("/vm;component/h.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check what kind of build action you chose for your image (page, resource, embedded resource, content...). You can do this by checking properties window of your image in Visual Studio.

Then check how to define correct uri path for your image. It depends on your file 's location. Please refer to [Pack URIs in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619709/how-to-binding-image-from-view-model-in-another-dll) for details.